# Getting Mulitiple App Icons on ios7 device

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, ios7, xcode5

Im getting a strange bug on ios7 (iPhone5 device). I installed iPhone app using xcode5 on ios7
my problem is whenever I install my app on the device, I'm getting my app icons multiple 
times with same name, I also tried for different apps through my system. I'm getting the same problem, even duplicate icon image not deleting from my device.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Does every time you run your app, a new icon appear on your springboard?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i mean when i was download my app(ipa file) from server on ios7 device i got original app icon image and as well as download processing image like ios7 default image comming with my app name, even im unable to delete that image from my ios7 device

Comment: I believe I'm experiencing the same issue. Initially, installing the app creates the single default / blank app icon with the loading-progress-circle and the text "Installing..." underneath. When the progress circle completes the actual app icon appears next to it with the correct app name, but the default/Installing icon never goes away, and I also can't delete it. I've restarted the phone and deleted the app itself - but that default icon sticks around...

Answer (score 3):

I also have similar issue. the installation icon with a "download circle" is left behind. I have a workaround to delete this extra icon. Try to install the app again and when device is downloading the app, delete the icon!

I also observed that when I upload the same ipa on testflight, or use itune directly, it work without leaving another icon behind.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when downloading the app from server. The issue occurs when there is a conflict with the bundle identifier in your info.plist in your app bundle and the bundle identifier in the plist file on the server from which you download your ipa. If both the bundle identifier are of exact match, you will not run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure all the app icon dimensions are correct? I don't know if that would help at all. Another thing you should try is loading the app onto another iPhone that isn't yours to see if it is on your Computers side or just your phones problem.