# Strange behavior while installing the binary in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, iphone-5

I developed an app for iPhone in xcode 4.6, i got a strange behavior while installing the ipa file in my iOS7 device from server.My app icon appears twice. App works fine with a original icon but the duplicate one ... even i am unable to delete it. you can observe in the below screenshot..

[image: please check the marked icons]

please check the marked icons. Please help me to get out of this issue. it only happens for ios7, same binary works fine in ios6 device with single app icon.

Comment: @Babul you linked the same question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph

Comment: Also having same issue; related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151562/getting-mulitiple-app-icons-on-ios7-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem will solve, please reinstall the binary again then it will show waiting icon, that time delete that icon and follow the below icons on your xocde see this is the universal app so im using all images, if your are running on xcode4.6.3 then use Icon-60@2x.png for iphone and Icon-76.png and Icon-76@2x.png for ipad [image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when downloading the app from server. The issue occurs when there is a conflict with the bundle identifier in your info.plist in your app bundle and the bundle identifier in the plist file on the server from which you download your ipa. If both the bundle identifier are of exact match, you will not run into this issue.